# highlight the duplicate row values with background color in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Im trying to Highlight the row with duplicate values depends upon the count in a specific background color.

for example.

If the no. of duplicate values is 2, the bgcolor in "green".

IF the count is 3, the bgcolor is in "red".

I need the expression for that process.

Any Help!

Comment: thanks for reply...Adrian..

I created the report and show the background color depends upon the value in the column,

for example,
=iif(Fields!name.Value="soundar","LightBlue",
 iif(Fields!name.Value="soundar1","Silver",
 "DarkSeaGreen"))

Comment: Here the duplicate record is "soundar" and "soundar1".Now i want to identify the duplicate records in column and show that in background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say I have some simple data like this:

[image]

If I'm setting up highlighting based on *ID*, I would make sure this is a group based on this column, e.g.

[image]

Then, for the **BackgroundColor** property I would use an expression like:

```
=Switch(Count(Fields!ID.Value, "IDGroup") = 3, "Red"
    , Count(Fields!ID.Value, "IDGroup") = 2, "Green")
```

So for each detail row, count the *ID* values in the *ID* group and set the colour accordingly. Works for my data:

[image]

Comment: Hi..Ian..when i create a group under a row groups means, the appearance of the whole report is changed..why it is happend

Comment: The designer will automatically add a row header column when adding new row groups. Just delete the new column and choose **Delete columns only** when prompted. This way you get the group without new columns being added to the report.

Comment: it works .IAN. only the order of the report is changed.Is it possible to show that in same order.

Comment: **Sorting** can be set at the Tablix and each group level. When you create a group it will be sorted by the grouping item by default. You should check the Sorting at each Tablix/group level - you're probably getting a mismatch at some point. I would start by deleting all but the lowest level of Sorting and see if that helps. You can check this under **Tablix Properties** and **Group Properties** - both have a Sorting section.

Comment: this answer is correct and is a very clever answer although if you go onto the MSDN website they do advise using IIF statement instead of switch

Comment: Hi Ian...Thanks a lot for all your suggestions.Its really valuable to me.its help me to solve the problem.Need your help in future.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's answer should be correct. If there's any reason why that doesn't work for you, you can try to use the [LookupSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) function which returns an array and the length property which returns the size of the array.

On your BackgroundColor property then you can write something like:

```
=Switch(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, "dataset").Length = 3, "Red", 
LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, "dataset").Length = 2, "Green")
```

Comment: Thanks Joao...sorry im new to ssrs.you mentioned "dataset" in your expression..why we need dataset?

Comment: "dataset" is the name of your dataset (just rename it to the appropriate name), the LookupSet function let's you search for a value from the current dataset, i.e. the dataset associated to the tablix, in a different dataset (or the same). So in my example, basically you are looking for all occurrences of ID (1st parameter) that match ID on the destination dataset (2nd parameter) and returning an array of all the ID (3rd parameter) where 1st and 2nd parameters match. The 4th parameter is the destination dataset.

Comment: Now i got it.Joao.thanks for you explanation...it really helps me a lot.

Comment: Feel free to message whenever glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the column 
go to background
choose expression copy and paste this code in and change the "COLUMN" to the column name

```
=IIF(COLUMN = 2, "Green",IIF(COLUMN = 2, "Red","White"))
```

Comment: soundarrajan please mark as complete and correct answer if this worked for you

Comment: there should be a tick to the left of my answer if you tick that will be marked as answered

Comment: ok luke.got it. Thanks to help to solve my issue and also suggest  Ian answer  is correct..you give really valuable suggestion to me. Need your help in future.